# Call function by Enter key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qkeyevent

How can I make (on_click) works when QPushButton ("click") is pressed by Enter keyboard key? it only interacts with mouse_click

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.label = QLabel("",self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)

        self.button = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.button.move(100, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.setGeometry(500, 150, 200, 200)
        self.show()    

    def on_click(self):
        self.label.setText("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Example()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you want the on_click function to be called when you press Enter keyboard key?

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: Your title is inappropriate, because for this it is not necessary to interact with the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite the keyPressEvent method:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.label = QLabel("",self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)

        self.button = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.button.move(100, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.setGeometry(500, 150, 200, 200)
        self.show()    

    def on_click(self):
        self.label.setText("Hello")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            self.on_click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Example()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution regarding this: [keyPressEvent() method doesn't work for PyQt5 / Python 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443523/keypressevent-method-doesnt-work-for-pyqt5-python-3/68649543#68649543).

You need to override the function in super class.

```
MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent
```